# c# How to get properties of a static class instance

Tags: c#

How can i get the public properties from a static instance of a class?

Example

```
public record MyClass{

 public static MyClass Instance1 = new(true);
 public static MyClass Instance2 = new(false);


 public bool MyParam {get;init;}

 private MyClass(bool myParam){
   MyParam = myParam;
 }

}
```

And I would like to access the value of MyParam from the static instances Instance1, Instance2.

Edit: sorry for the bad details. I want to do this all via reflection. Get all the static instances of the class, and for each instance the value of the param.

Comment: `MyClass.Instance1.MyParam`?

Comment: "all the static instances of the class" there **is** no instance when using `static`.

Comment: *"static class instance"* is an oxymoron and contradictory

Comment: the actual question here seems to be "how to get the values of the static fields `MyInstance1` and `MyInstance2`, to which the dupe clearly points out the solution. Once you got those values, you can easily access their `MyParam`-properties.

Answer (score 2):

Based on how you wrote your code, you can accessit as `MyClass.Instance1.MyParam`

For example (Try it out here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nwBbkH#)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Here we are accessing MyParam
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Instance1.MyParam);
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Instance2.MyParam);
    }
}

public record MyClass
{
    public static MyClass Instance1 = new(true);
    public static MyClass Instance2 = new(false);
    public bool MyParam
    {
        get;
        init;
    }

    private MyClass(bool myParam)
    {
        MyParam = myParam;
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad for not being clear enough. This was overly simplified example. What I want to do is get all the instances via reflection, and then the values for each instance.

Comment: why reflection? why dont you create a collection and place all instances in there? I can help you with the reflection as well, but there might be easier ways of solving it